# little question about the process of finding the extremum

Tags: calculus

I noticed in *calculus* written by Григо́рий Миха́йлович Фихтенго́льц, a chapter on extremum introduced the sufficient conditions for finding it.
Suppose f(x) is devirable at least in $[x_0 -ε,x_0+ε](x≠x_0)$,then there are 3 cases:

1. when $x < x_0,f'(x) > 0; x < x_0,f'(x) < 0;$

2.when $x < x_0,f'(x) < 0,;x < x_0,f'(x) > 0;$

3.when $x <x_0 or  x> x_0,f'(x) < 0 or f'(x) > 0 $

then the author analyzed every case, such as in 1
when $ x < x_0 $, f(x) increases in  $[x_0-ε,x_0] $, when x < x_0,f(x) decreases in  $[x_0,x_0+ε] $,then  $f(x_0)  $is the extremum. I just wonder if f(x) is not continuous at  $x0 $(as the picture represents, $x_0=(5,6) $[image]),then he can only say f(x) increases in $ [x_0-ε,x_0) $ rather than in  $[x_0-ε,x_0]. $

Comment: Please use MathJax for typesetting formulas. Moreover there should be some typos in your bullet points as in this form they are not consistent

Comment: I suppose Fichtenholz was considering function that is differentiable in some $\varepsilon$-neighbourhood of point $x_1$ where $f'(x_1)=0$. This requires for $f(x)$ to be continuous in $\varepsilon$-neighbourhood and excludes your case.